# Suspend computer with a regular user (Windows Server 2008 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, suspend

I have a server 2008 R2 as a Workstation, with Active Directory set up, an Admin and a regular Domain User.

With the Administrator I'm able to suspend/hibernate the computer and I'd like to do the same with the regular user (the one I normally use for security). Where's the setting to enable it?

P.S.: Hyper-V role is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be under your local Security Policy. Under User rights, I believe you need to add the group "Interactive" to allow any user who is logged into the local console to shutdown the system.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to find any Interactive group to add to the Domain User!

Comment: You don't add Interactive to Domain User. Look under Local Security, then User Rights in **secpol.msc**. Under **Shutdown the system**, add the group **Interactive**.